# agent for receipt of legal correspondence

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "agent for receipt of legal correspondence" proper in English? Why not just "agent for legal correspondence"?

> Shell companies may be registered to the address of a company that provides a service setting up shell companies, and which may act as the **agent for receipt of legal correspondence** (such as an accountant or lawyer). The company may serve as a vehicle for business transactions without itself having any significant assets or operations.

> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_corporation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is proper.

The only reason for not "agent for legal correspondence" is that the meaning is different.  The accountant or lawyer act as the person who legally *receives* official letters written to the company. They don't have to read the letters or reply to them.

There is a law that says that every company must have a publically registered address and someone who will receive any letters posted to that address (such as demands for payment or court orders)  That person is the agent for the receipt of legal correspondence.  But that person doesn't have to send any letters or do anything else, so they aren't the agent for *sending* legal correspondence.

Comment: It should be noted that often the registered address is *not* a company office, just an agent who receives mail and process for hundreds or even thousands of companies. One particular building in Delaware is the registered address for over half the Fortune 1000!